# Check if the returned object is of expected subclass in C++ unit test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, type-safety

I have a function that returns object of abstract class.

```
AbstractClass some_function(int argument);
```

I have an assumption that if `argument == 1` then `some_function` should return object of `DerivedClassOne` and if `argument == 2` it should be `DerivedClassTwo`. I want to check these assumptions with a simple unit test.

What's the best (simple, readable, reliable and independent of any third-party libraries and tools) way to check that?

Comment: If the return type is `AbstractClass` then the returned object will always be `AbstractClass`.

Comment: `DerivedClassOne* derivedOne = dynamic_cast<DerivedClassOne>(result);` If result is not DerviedClassOne, then derivedOne will be nullptr. And you need to change your function to return a pointer to AbstractClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `some_function()` is returning an `AbstractClass` **by value**, which means the returned object gets sliced and will always be just a `AbstractClass` by itself.  Polymorphism only works with pointers and references.  Either way, you can use `dynamic_cast` for your validation check.

For example:

```
AbstractClass* some_function(int argument);

...

AbstractClass *obj;

obj = some_function(1);
if (dynamic_cast<DerivedClassOne*>(obj) != NULL)
    // returned the correct type...
else
    // returned the wrong type...

obj = some_function(2);
if (dynamic_cast<DerivedClassTwo*>(obj) != NULL)
    // returned the correct type...
else
    // returned the wrong type...
```

Or:

```
AbstractClass& some_function(int argument);

...

try {
    dynamic_cast<DerivedClassOne&>(some_function(1));
    // returned the correct type...
}
catch (const std::bad_cast&) {
    // returned the wrong type...
}

try {
    dynamic_cast<DerivedClassTwo&>(some_function(2));
    // returned the correct type...
}
catch (const std::bad_cast&) {
    // returned the wrong type...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Coming from C# (mostly), I didn't grasp the whole difference about returning values by value, reference and pointer.

Comment: "Which means the returned object gets sliced" left me confused. Can you please explain what it means and how it works, exactly?

Comment: See [What is object slicing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: Thanks again. After reading this, and a lot of other resources, I came up with a new question as a follow-up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28995502/how-to-properly-implement-creation-and-allocation-of-a-list-of-objects-known-o

Answer (score 1):

Use `dynamic_cast`, which will result in a NULL pointer if the object isn't of the expected subclass. From Wikipedia:

```
int main()
{
    Base* basePointer = new Derived();
    Derived* derivedPointer = NULL;

    // To find whether basePointer is pointing to Derived type of object
    derivedPointer = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(basePointer);

    if (derivedPointer != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "basePointer is pointing to a Derived class object"; // Identified
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "basePointer is NOT pointing to a Derived class object";
    }

    // Requires virtual destructor 
    delete basePointer;
    basePointer = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can I make this work with references instead of pointers?

Comment: `Base *base = new Derived; dynamic_cast<Derived&>(*base)`.  If the cast fails, an `std::bad_cast` exception is thrown (since a reference cannot be null).